# Can I send mail without opening mail app using IONIC in both Android and IOS?

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to send mail on click of a button without opening mail application using IONIC only. Is this possible in IOS and ANDROID? I have used email composer but it opens mail application.

Comment: you can ask server to do that but not using built in system email

Comment: If you have a dedicated server to do that, of course you can

Comment: I would check out [mailgun](https://www.mailgun.com/) if you want to perform this kind of functionality. You cannot do it from the phone itself, just from a 3rd party.

Answer (score 0):

So the logic here is that it would be actually pretty bad (for users) if mobile apps / web-apps would gain ability to send emails without user's explicit action to do so. Think of spam bot networks that would emerge etc.

You have 2 options:

- create your own server side logic (API) that clients call to and
  perform email action via an "email as a service".
- help user to open email client with "pre-filled" email details

For #1 you can use sendgrid.com and similar services, so that your own service could call sendgrid and dispatch emails/

For #2 there are simple web techniques (not ideal though) like so:

```
submitIdea() {
    let formattedBody = `Hi, here is my idea...: \n \n \n`;
    window.location.href = `mailto:ideas@yourdomain.com?subject=Idea for web app from ${this.foundation.userData.user.nickname}&body=`+encodeURIComponent(formattedBody);
    this.foundation.analytics.track("idea", "user clicked submit button");
};
```

This will open app default email client and will help user to type less of text or supply certain app details automatically.

I used this to help with user support / feedback type of emails, where app version etc context can be auto populated.